# How to ask my workplace to amend my leaving date

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, education

I work in a special educational needs school. I sent my resignation letter to the Head Teacher yesterday, giving 4 weeks notice. It works out well, as my last day actually falls on the last day of term before May half term. However, it occurred to me after I had sent the resignation letter that I maybe should've set my leaving date to a week later, so that I'm paid for the whole month, as I need all the money I can get if I'm being honest.

I want to ask them whether this would be possible, but I want to ask in a more professional manner than "I want to be paid for the whole month".

I feel I should add that I am leaving on a very positive note with the school, and that I am also aware that my might say no. If that's the case, at least I'll know I tried.

Answer (score 5):

You ask by politely asking. It's not a very reasonable request, but not very unreasonable either.

They may say no; they may have already scheduled your replacement's starting date, or they may have already reallocated the funds that would have paid your salary. They may just say no on principle.

Personally,I don't see any reason they'd particularly want to pay you the extra week, unless you'll be doing something that is worth that money to them. All they might need you for at that point is grading, right?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to ask them whether this would be possible, but I want to ask
> in a more professional manner than "I want to be paid for the whole
> month".

When a person turns in their resignation I assume the date they are turning in the letter was picked because:

- this is the last day I can do this and still serve my notice period, and start my new job when the new place wants me to start.
- or I just decided last night to quit, and so I am giving notice now, so I can be out the door as soon as possible even if I don't have a job.

If somebody wants to delay leaving I wonder what happened to their plans. If the change is requested nicely and very soon after the original request and I don't have a replacement arranged, then if i trust the reason I might agree to it.

The more well defined the exit process is, the harder it is to stop once the process has started. So even a good reason might not help.

> However, it occurred to me after I had sent the resignation letter
> that I maybe should've set my leaving date to a week later, so that
> I'm paid for the whole month, as I need all the money I can get if I'm
> being honest.

If the only reason is I get to pay you more for the same work, I probably won't do anything to help. I have known companies to waive some of the notice period so that they can force the last day be the end of the month, so that benefits don't go into the next month, or they set the day so they don't give you a paid day off for the national holiday.

You can ask politely, and expect to provide a reason. Then hope they will accommodate your request.